# What's the cheapest public transportation option to get from Ventimiglia (in Italy) to Antibes?

Tags: budget, trains, france, buses, italy

I want to get from Ventimiglia to Antibes using public transport.

I know that the TER train costs about 10 Euros. Is there a cheaper way (a bus maybe?)

Comment: The cheapest way is walking or hitchhiking. Could you please be more specific on the details of your journey? Do you have a certain amount of time available for the trip?

Comment: Are you prepared to hitchhike?

Comment: Agreed that the question is bad. But I guess what you want to know is: There are buses from Menton to Nice (100) and then from Nice to Antibes (200). A ticket is 1,5 euros but you'll probably need 2. The trip is probably over 3 hours long (buses are usually late).

Comment: there. I made it more specific

Answer (score 4):

Public transit is often managed by local governments and therefore lines end at the border of their territory.

I suppose the train continues to Italy for international cooperation or historical reason (also simply because there is a need for public transit). But other transit systems don't go as far as Italy, buses are managed by the *Departement des Alpes Maritimes*, and therefore limited to France.

There are buses between Menton (close to Italian border) and Nice ([line 100](http://www.cg06.fr/cms/cg06/upload/servir-les-habitants/fr/files/100.pdf), taking about 1h30) and between Nice and Antibes ([line 200](http://www.cg06.fr/cms/cg06/upload/servir-les-habitants/fr/files/200.pdf), taking about 1h30). They come often but are usually late.

A ticket on this network costs 1 euro and not valid for transfer, so you'll have to buy 2.

The train from Ventimiglia to Menton costs 2,40 euros (full fare) so you can go down to a total of 4,40 euros.

**Note:** you will probably lose a minimum of half a day (it'll take 4h+) to save 5 euros. If I were you I'd take a look at discounts on trains. If you are under 26, you can have 25% off when travelling off-peak. If you plan to travel along the Mediterranean sea in France, you can take a look at the [*Carte Zou*](http://www.ter-sncf.com/Regions/paca/Fr/Se_deplacer_en_TER/Avant_mon_voyage/Produits_et_prix/DetailProduit.aspx?action=liste&ctcr=KR05). It costs 15 or 30 euros depending on your age and you always have 50% off (so on a Ventimiglia-Antibes round-trip you already save 10 euros). It's not made for tourists but I guess you can use a fake address like your hotel's.

Comment: The ticket price has been raised to 1,5 Euro. http://www.lignesdazur.com/presentation/?rub_code=1006

Comment: @Midhat yeah I saw that website and I am not sure, this website is for Nice city transit, so it may not concern intercity lines. In doubt, you'd better expect to pay 1,5 euros and you'll see. By the way, they also talk about a 1,5 euros ticket that offers transfer, so about your answer, it would mean 1,5 euro for Ventimiglia-Nice, and 1 to 1,5 euros for Nice-Antibes.

Comment: Btw, the link for the prices : http://www.cg06.fr/cms/cg06/upload/servir-les-habitants/fr/files/gtarif.pdf NCA means that you stay around Nice. So if these prices are still up-to-date, it is 1 euro for a single trip, 1,5 euro with a transfer. Also, be careful with the 905, there are at most 4 buses a day.

Comment: Regarding the institutional background: Geneva busses go quite far into France and the Basel tramway network also includes one stop in France so if there is a will and money, it's not completely impossible.

Answer (score 2):

There is Bus 905 from Ventimiglia to Menton, but it works only during daytime

http://www.cg06.fr/cms/cg06/upload/servir-les-habitants/fr/files/905.pdf

So the Itinerary becomes bus 905, 100 and then 200. The ticket cost is 1,5 euro each, so this brings the total price to 4,5 Euros